# Login ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am currently developing one application using MVC 3... Now I'm stuck at a login roles...

How to create login site with different roles? I mean when admin logs in I want to redirect to backend pages, and when it is a normal user redirect to the site. I've already set ROLE for administrators that is ok, but not for users...

```
    [Authorize(Roles = "user")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [Authorize(Roles = "Administrators")]
    public ActionResult view()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

How about in account controller, I need to set redirect page or how?

Answer (score 8):

In the LogOn method you could redirect to the corresponding view based on the username:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (MembershipService.ValidateUser(model.Username, model.Password))
        {
            FormsService.SignIn(model.Username, false);
            if (string.Equals("admin", model.Username))
            {
                // If the admin user logged in
                // redirect to a different action
                return RedirectToAction("View", "Home");
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
        }
    }
    return View(model);
}
```